# Does AWS Neptune support text search and sorting with Gremlin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm using AWS Neptune with Gremlin. Is there a way of using wildcard for search like **' % title % '** & sorting something with order by **asc / desc** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neptune supports Order().by() you just need to use the ‘incr’ and ‘decr’ Keywords.

There is currently no wildcard support. You can simulate a starts with semantic using the between() step however.

Additional text predicates are being added to ApacheTinkerpop in an upcoming release and this is definitely recognized as a common use case. I expect to see additional text support added to Neptune over time as well.

UPDATED (November 17th 2019) :

Amazon Neptune now supports the Apache TinkerPop 3.4.1 release. This release added additional text predicates such as `startingWith`, `endingWith` and `containing` to the Gremlin language.

Cheers
Kelvin

Comment: Is this still the case in March 2019? Thanks.

Comment: Or November 2019?  Where can I look to find out what Neptune supports?

Comment: Amazon Neptune now supports Apache TinkerPop 3.4.1 so you can use the Gremlin text predicates that were added in 3.4 such as startingWith and endingWith. Here is a blog post that discusses those features. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-neptune-now-supports-tinkerpop-3-4-features/

Answer (score 2):

Now you can also plug Neptune to the Elastic Search for enhanced Full-text search capabilities: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/full-text-search.html